# Intercept method calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, es6-proxy

What's the equivalent of the `__call` magic method from PHP ?

I was under the impression that Proxy can do this, but it can't.

```
class MyClass{
  constructor(){
    return new Proxy(this, {
      apply: function(target, thisArg, args){
        console.log('call', thisArg, args);
        return 'test';
      },

      get: function(target, prop){
        console.log('get', prop, arguments);
      }


    });

  }

}

var inst = new MyClass();
console.log(inst.foo(123));
```

`get` seems to work because I see "get foo", but `apply` does not. I get is not a function error.

Comment: The `apply` trap on the proxy if for calling the object itself, i.e. `inst(…)`. However you cannot create a callable proxy from a non-callable target.

Comment: Your `get` trap on the `.foo` property must return a function so that you can call it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842477/mixing-constructor-and-apply-traps-on-the-javascript-proxy-object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027225/in-the-proxy-handler-how-to-distiguish-getting-a-property-var-vs-calling-a-me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply) actually handles a function call *to the object itself*, i.e. if you do `new Proxy(someFunction, { apply: ... })`, `apply` would be called before `someFunction` is called.

There is nothing for trapping a call to a property, because this would be superfluous – `get` already handles when a property is returned. You can simply return a function that then produces some debug output when called.

```js
class MyClass{
  constructor(){
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get: function(target, prop) {
        return function() {
          console.log('function call', prop, arguments);
          return 42;
        };
      }
    });
  }
}

var inst = new MyClass();
console.log(inst.foo(123));
```

Comment: I don't think this is a complete solution. you have returned a static value. you need to use `apply` inside `get` to calculate result of original function.

Comment: @BadisMerabet I'm sure OP can modify the function to suit their needs. Nevertheless the question was an analogue to `__call` in PHP, which is used to resolve non-existent functions of an object, i.e. there is no "original function" to call. The default / intended behaviour of `Proxy` is [well-documented already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: thank you for clarifying this, It makes sense. Still I am interested in what's the goal or benefits of intercepting calls to non existing functions in a piece of code or software ?

Comment: @BadisMerabet I know that this sort of "magic" (comparable to macros in some languages, and runtime reflection in others) can be used to implement e.g. ORM systems, where methods may be generated dynamically for one-to-many relations. Some other uses I can think of – a library with lazily loaded modules/functions, libraries which have (too) many functions that all have a given pattern (e.g. a geometry library – `addPoint2D`, `addPoint3D`, …). There are lots of applications, and perhaps they are not indicative of "good" code always, but this *is* Javascript after all. :)

Answer (score 4):

This another way of achieving what you have requested.

```js
class MyClass{
  constructor(){
     return new Proxy(this, {
        get(target, propKey, receiver) {
            const origMethod = target[propKey];
            return function (...args) {
                let result = origMethod.apply(this, args);
                console.log(propKey + JSON.stringify(args)
                    + ' -> ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                return result;
            };
        }
    });
  }
  
foo = (x) => {
  return x + 1;
};

}

var inst = new MyClass();
console.log(inst.foo(123));
```

Comment: Great ! This intercepts all method calls to an object, even if a method does not actually exist.

Comment: Your code should be marked as the correct answer. It includes the redirect to the class methods. Thanks for such clean implementation

Answer (score 2):

Yeah Proxy can do that, but even when trapping methods you have to use `get` of Proxy.

Then here I also executes your real method, but I don't know if you want to mock it.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (typeof target[prop] !== "function") {
          return "etcetcetc";
        }
        return function(...args) {
          console.log('call', args);
          return target[prop]();
        };
      }
    });
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('I am foo!');
  }
}

var inst = new MyClass();
inst.foo(123);
```

As you can see, if you are calling a method of your instance, I will intercept it, and then return your original method execution.

If you are accessing an attribute of your instance, I will return always a mocked string.

Then of course change it with the behavior that you want to.